# Why angular service is get undefined?

Tags: angularjs

This is a simple calculator using angular.
addScv is not getting as a service.How can I fix this?Here I have added service only for the addition part.

My code -

```
var name="myApp";
requires=[];
app=angular.module(name,requires);

app.service("addSvc",  function() {
  this.add = function(firstNum, secondNum) {
    return parseInt(firstNum) + parseInt(secondNum);
  }
})


app.controller('calcCtrl',function($scope,addSvc){
console.log("calcCtrl works!");
var opp;
ans=0;
opp=$scope.singleSelect;
console.log(opp);

 $scope.calculateNums=function(a,b){
   console.log("function works!");
         console.log($scope.n1);
         console.log($scope.n2);
         console.log($scope.singleSelect);
         if($scope.singleSelect=="+"){
           ans= addScv.add(a,b);
           console.log(ans);
         }else if ($scope.singleSelect=="-"){
             ans= (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
         }else if ($scope.singleSelect=="*"){
             ans= (parseInt(a) * parseInt(b));
         }else if ($scope.singleSelect=="/"){
             ans= (parseInt(a) / parseInt(b));
         }
         console.log(ans);
         return ans;

       }

});

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hello</h3>
<div ng-controller='calcCtrl' >
Number 1::<input Type="text" name="number1" ng-model="n1"/ required> <br/>
Number 2::<input Type="text" name="number2" ng-model="n2"/ required> <br/>
operator::<select ng-model="singleSelect">
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option  value="*" >*</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
     </select></p> <br/>

<button ng-click="calculateNums(n1,n2)">Calculate Now</button>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code identifies the inserted values.
The output

```
calcCtrl works!
app.js:20 undefined
app.js:23 function works!
app.js:24 2
app.js:25 3
app.js:26 +
angular.js:9505 ReferenceError: addScv is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.calculateNums (app.js:28)
    at angular.js:10290
    at angular.js:18784
    at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:12069)
    at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:12167)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:18783)
    at angular.js:2671
    at forEach (angular.js:329)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:2670)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9505
(anonymous) @ angular.js:6947
$apply @ angular.js:12169
(anonymous) @ angular.js:18783
(anonymous) @ angular.js:2671
forEach @ angular.js:329
eventHandler @ angular.js:2670
```

Here it doesn't give the answer as well.
Without a service above code works correctly.
hope a clear explanation.Thanks.

Comment: (for your service) it's a typo: `addScv` != `addSvc`

Comment: I'm assuming your `$scope.singleSelect` is a collection of checkboxes/buttons of some sort that allow you to select mathematical operations. It probably is initialised as _undefined_ (not selected as anything). You can initialise in the controller `$scope.singleSelect = '+';` or use `ng-init="singleSelect='+'"`

Comment: can you please define `ans` as `var`, `var ans = 0`